# Why am I encountering a Segmentation Fault when accessing Inherited Variables from a wxWidgets event?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm currently developing an app in C++ using wxWidgets. I currently have a class `ArchetypeTable` which derives from the `wxListCtrl` class, and it has a number of functions which I have declared that are meant to be used by the `MainWindow` class's Event Handlers. However, I'm experiencing an unusual behavior: Whenever I try to access any of the `wxListCtrl`'s functions or members,that is, the variables and members which I have inherited in my `ArchetypeTable` class, I encounter a Segmentation Fault. This only occurs when I attempt access an inherited function or member from within the body of the Event Handler function, or from within any function called within those Event Handlers. These functions work fine in other contexts, such when called from within the `ArchetypeTable` or the `MainWindow`'s constructor.

Below is my code. I've trimmed out some irrelevant pieces.

**main-window.cpp**

```
#include "main-window.h"
#include "archetype-table.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(const wxString& title, int width, int height)
  : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(width, height)) {
  m_MainPanel = new wxPanel(this);
  

  m_ClassDropdown = new wxComboBox(m_MainPanel, wxID_ANY, wxT("Select a class..."), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, GetClassList(), wxCB_SORT | wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER);

  ArchetypeTable* m_ArchetypeTable = new ArchetypeTable(m_MainPanel);

  m_TransferButton = new wxButton(m_MainPanel, wxID_ANY, "Select an Archetype...");

  // Apply Sizers to all objects
  wxBoxSizer* rootSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
  rootSizer->Add(m_MainPanel, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 10);
  rootSizer->SetSizeHints(this);
  this->SetSizerAndFit(rootSizer);

  wxFlexGridSizer* mainSizer = new wxFlexGridSizer(1, 5, 5);
  mainSizer->AddGrowableCol(0);
  mainSizer->AddGrowableRow(1);
  mainSizer->Add(m_ClassDropdown, 0, wxALIGN_RIGHT);
  mainSizer->Add(m_ArchetypeTable, 1, wxEXPAND);
  mainSizer->Add(m_TransferButton, 0, wxALIGN_RIGHT);
  mainSizer->SetSizeHints(this);
  m_MainPanel->SetSizerAndFit(mainSizer);

  // Bind all events
  m_TransferButton->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MainWindow::OnTransferButtonClick, this);

  // Center the window on the screen.
  Centre();
}

void MainWindow::OnTransferButtonClick(wxCommandEvent &event) {
  // Problematic function. This call causes a Segmentation Fault.
  m_ArchetypeTable->ClearAll();
}
```

**archetype-table.cpp**

```
#include "archetype-table.h"
#include "pf-class-list.h"

ArchetypeTable::ArchetypeTable(wxWindow* parent) : wxListCtrl(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxLC_REPORT) { }

void ArchetypeTable::PopulateTable(wxCommandEvent &event) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: First thing to do: learn the basics of your debugger.

Comment: `ArchetypeTable* m_ArchetypeTable = ...` Um... I'm gonna suggest, site-unseen but based on the rest of your member variables in this function, you already *have* a `m_ArchetypeTable` **member variable** in the `MainWindow` class, and this little gem is shadow-hiding it from you by declaring a local automatic variable named  `m_ArchetypeTable` for the duration of this function. Short answer: lose the `ArchetypeTable*` preamble of that line.

Comment: Whew @WhozCraig, you always have your crystal ball polished for clarity, but that may be one of the best rabbits I've see you pull out of your hat! That would surely do it.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's absolutely the source of my issues. Feeling blind to not have seen that devilish detail- I'd been doing some absolute basic tests of the class in the constructor and I never deleted the declaration when I made it into a member variable. I'll be closing this question.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Surely I've never made the same mistake... right ? :-P <derp>

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by WhozCraig, the source of this issue was that the `ArchetypeTable` that this was being performed on had been declared both as a class variable and then subsequently hidden by a second declaration in the Constructor. The table created is going out of scope, and so when the function calls are made on the underlying, undeclared object, undefined behavior ensues.